# Send request to diff host from client browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

HI!

for example i have site1.com 
Is it possible to send request from site1.com page witch loads in client browser, to other sites site2.com etc (i have no access to them) and parse result data?
Is it possible to do it via javascript and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax cross domain call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for security reasons (and blocked by [the same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), the only thing you can fetch is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) across domains (since it's a single GET), otherwise you have to proxy requests through the domain the parent page is on.