# Avoid x-domain solutions

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-server

I'm currently working on a web application that customers can add to their webpages by adding a javascript link to a js file on my server. The application read all the javascriptfiles from my sever, but I still get an error when trying to use ajax to get data from my database. I didn't think that would be a problem because the files is on my server.

Can I fix this or do I have to make a cross-browser solution? I don't have any control over the costumers server.

Thanks in advance

Mikael

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible: When you execute a remote script, it runs in the context of the containing document.

There are some popular workarounds for this:

- Using an `iframe`, which fixes the cross-domain problem but doesn't integrate well with the remote site (e.g. no custom styling)
- Using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to make cross-domain Ajax requests (detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call))
- Using a server-side proxy script (not an option in this scenario)
- Using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (I'm not familiar with this but it's said to work)

Comment: I created my own json provider with help from http://www.carolinamantis.com/wordpress/?p=29 works great!

Answer (score 1):

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is based on the **host document** not the script itself.

You need to use a [cross domain ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+domain+ajax) technique.