# Load external website into my own website through ajax

Tags: ajax, hyperlink

Is it possible to load an external website into my own existing page?

Or, is this a security risk, and will it not be allowed, or is it too uncommon and a burden to accomplish?

If so, would I need to make an ajax call to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Answer (score 0):

Ajax: Won't work *easely*. It's called cross-domain ajax requests and it's not easy to implement (see http://www.peachpit.com/blogs/blog.aspx?uk=Performing-Cross-Domain-Ajax-Requests).

IFrame: Will work.

Comment: This is true for pretty much all browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Is there any chance you can load data into an iframe and then pull the data out using javascript?