# JSON Data and Manipulating the Content

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I am trying to write out the data from this JSON url into li's.

The JSON link is https://www.inquicker.com/facility/americas-family-doctors.json

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JQuery (cross-domain) JSONP</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://www.inquicker.com/facility/americas-family-doctors.json', 
        function(data){ 
        alert(data.facility);
        $.each(data.schedules, function(i, name){
            $('#names').append('<li>' + name.available_times[0] + '</li>');
        });
    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul id="names"></ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Currently this is writing out undefined and object object. The undefined is because there isn't any available times, and object object is an available time. I need to be able to write out the content of the JSON file to a list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a JSFidle  check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VVnSC/). You to check the data is available in  available_times then proceed.
`if (name.available_times.length){.......
.....
....`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('https://www.inquicker.com/facility/americas-family-doctors.json',
    function(data){

    $.each(data.schedules, function(i, name){
        times=''
            if (name.available_times.length){
                times='<ul>'
                times+='<li><a href="'+name.available_times[0].url+'">'+name.available_times[0].when+'</a></li>'
                times+='</ul>'
            }
            else{
               times='<ul><li>No Time Available</li></ul>'                    
            }
        $('#names').append('<li>' + (name.name) + times + '</li>');
    });
});
```

});

Comment: So you want to remove doctors name from the result and just want to show location and the available time ?

Comment: Updated the fidle check if this what you wanted. And as LeviBotelho noted i think you need to brush up basics of JSON. This is really simple.

Comment: Thats simple add a herf with data from available_times[0].url Check fiddle

Comment: There is some issue with JSfiddle my updates are not reflecting. I have updated my answer above. check this.

Comment: That code isn't working for me. Here is my fiddly with everything I have so far, and all I need is to get these times down to 1 (the next time for each location) http://jsfiddle.net/VVnSC/17/

Comment: Could you check the fiddle again?

Comment: Did you work on the fiddle to get the times to 1 for each location? If so what is the fiddle link? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a test to check if the length of `available_times` array is > 0 before accessing the first cell.

And then, you can access to when or url properties :

- `available_times[0].when`
- `available_times[0].url`

Edit : save `name.available_times[0]` in a temp var and write 
`temp.when` or `temp.url`.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON link, some `schedule`s have empty `available_times` arrays.

And `available_times[0]` is an object that contains the properties `when` and `url`, so you'll have to write `name.available_times[0].url`

Comment: I see what your saying, and I tried name.available_times[0].when, but it's throwing an error cannot read property of when undefined.

Comment: That's because not all avaiable_times arrays have elements. Some are empty arrays. Check http://pastebin.com/6DHzfBAS (schedule id 220 and 222)