# Cross domain AJAX results in 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

We are trying to make cross domain AJAX call via POST. If we directly try to access `bbb.com` from `aaa.com` it will ask for credentials. Only after giving credentials will we be able to access `bbb.com`. Now in the same way, when an AJAX call is made to a different domain, in this case `bbb.com` I'm receiving a 403 forbidden error.

I tried adding the authorization header and now in the request header, I see the below headers but even after having authorization header I'm still having the issue.

> Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Access-Control-Request-He...    authenticationindicator,authorizationtoken
>   Access-Control-Request-Me...    POST
>   Authorization   Basic TG9uZG9uOkJiZ0JlbjE4NTk=
>   Cache-Control   no-cache
>   Host    aaa.com
>   Origin  bbb.com
>   Pragma  no-cache
>   Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
>   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0

Does anyone know how we can solve the 403 forbidden issue?

Comment: What does bbb.com reply when you make the same request from bbb.com (same orogin)? A 403 does not produced by the same-origin policy restriction but provided by your server on bbb.com due to it's configuration, etc.

Comment: You are problably looking for a JSONP solution or set up a server-side proxy that handles the request towards the other domain. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a Cross Origin issue - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You probably want to add something the headers returned from bbb.com, like so:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Hope that helps,
Chris

Comment: Of course this will only work if the OP can modify `bbb.com`.

Comment: Wouldn't this completely expose `bbb.com` to security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make cross-domain AJAX calls.

If you wan't to get some infos from another domain as your own, you can do it server site with PHP for example and then make an ajax call to your own php script.

Another solution is to use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Ya, but here it is a post request,not a get, so I cant use jsonp

Comment: You can, with CORS enabled.

Answer (score 1):

ajax doesnt allow cross domain calls. use jsonp for this purpose.
http://jsonp.jit.su/

Answer (score 1):

Ajax does not allow cross-domain calls. If you want to do it that way, you can make your Ajax code call PHP (or whatever you choose) code which can access bbb.com and you can return this data to the client.