# Cordova Ajax response 430 forbidden in ios Application

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, sapui5, cordova-3

I am trying to create a SAPUI5 Application and trying to run this app on the cordova ios platform, I am getting 403 forbidden response form the server while sending the jquery ajax request. The service is working fine, i have tried to run this in other ios application.

The problem is only with this application, even when i am running this sap application on the browser, it is working absolutely fine.

Do i need to do any changes in config.xml file.

Regards,
Harsh Jain

Answer (score 0):

Since you got a 403 response you may be hitting a cross-domain restriction.

Ajax requests can only be made to your same domain on the same port.

Two potential solutions would be using jsonp or a reverse-proxy server.

Here is a similar question: [Cross domain AJAX results in 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256732/cross-domain-ajax-results-in-403-forbidden)

Useful Links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to authenticate for access to the "server" site?

If so, you can try adding to the ajax request the properties:

**username**:""

**password**:""