# Ajax request works in remote server but not in local server (with Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've a web application wich makes Ajax requests to a server with Codeigniter-php code. The Ajax requests work correctly in local server but not when the application is hosted in remote server.
The console errors are:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/CI-example/index.php/control/controlHome. Origin http://www.page.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Surprisingly, the request is made in the server but not the response.

The URL that I use to Ajax request is:

```
AJAX_URL = "http://localhost/CI-example/site/index.php/control/controlHome";
```

But, also I've tried with:

```
AJAX_URL = "http://www.page.com/CI-example/site/index.php/control/controlHome";
```

And the next error is captured:

```
POST http://www.page.com/webdom/site/index.php/control/controlHome 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How can I do?

Edit:
www.page.com is a subdomain. Is necessary to do some configuration when a subdomain is used to Ajax request?

And the folders organization is:

```
/CI-example
---/application/controllers/control.php
---/system
---/site/js/ajaxRequest.js
```

Comment: Have you tried `AJAX_URL = "/CI-example/site/index.php/control/controlHome"`? You shouldn't need to include the host name since AJAX is only valid on internal requests.

Comment: Is it possible you've got a redirection? Try to call the URL in a separate tab and look at the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: @AustinMullins, I've tried it and the error is the last of the question

Comment: @Thomas. I think that there isn't redirection

Comment: @vicenrele, check Tatu's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Comment: Note that cross-domain requests can be done using JQuery ajax() with specific datatype "jsonp" if you are expecting json data. : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Given your folder organization, why there's a 'site' in your request URLs? And second thing, how did it even respond to that? Do you have virtual host config or routes added?

Comment: It would help if you included more of your source code in the question.

Comment: Could you fix the question's title, or the question ? The first sentence ("works on local, not on remote") contradicts the title.

Answer (score 1):

As I am getting here, while you are sending ajax requests to the server than it's returning `500 (Internal Server Error)`. I'm sure that the error is from server side, and there may be following reason-

1. If everything is fine in the codes, then may be your `base_url` is different from what you are requesting. Yes this can cause the problem, for example if you have hosted your web application and your `base_url` is `www.mysite.com` and you are requesting for `mysite.com`.
2. Next reason may be, that you have developed your project in windows or any system which is in-case-sensitive but when you will upload to any linux like server than each and every file name will be case-sensitive. For example suppose a model file name you have given is `MyModel.php` but when you will load the model, it will generate the error like Unable to find  the specific class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make HTTP POST requests using AJAX to a different domain, unless that page allows you to do so using a special header called "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

localhost is different to page.com which is why this will not work.

Comment: There is no way you would get that error if the source request originates from the same domain as the destination request domain.

Comment: Do you know if there any problem for be a subdomain and not domain?

Answer (score 0):

Response on the http://www.page.com's url say something has gone wrong during the page execution. Your PHP error log should help you to find what.

Adding the line `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` might return the error to the ajax request, in the error handler. Don't forget to remove the line after use, you don't want this lying around in production code.

Answer (score 0):

The second error is : `500 (Internal Server Error)`

This means there was an error on the server side - not a cross-origin policy problem.
This is probably an error in the execution of your PHP script.

Check your error log (e.g : if you use the standard LAMP stack, the error log should be somewhere in `/var/log/apache2/`)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
http://localhost/CI-example/index.php/control/controlHome
```

instead of

```
http://localhost/CI-example/site/index.php/control/controlHome
```

in your ajax URL.
As from your folder structure, there is no need to include "site" in your URL