# post json stringify response 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, json, post

I'm trying to post json data

```
 var details= jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getRowData');
$.post("someurl", { szVoucherNo: VoucherNo, dtmTransaction: Transaction, details: JSON.stringify(details) } );
```

but then i got 403 forbidden response from server.

Please could you tell me what I did wrong?

TIA

Comment: That's a problem with the server-side code, not with your JavaScript.

Comment: "A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server refuses to allow the requested action. In other words, the server can be reached, but the server declined to allow the requested access." [HTTP 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) Is this call going to another domain [different than the one you are on?]

Comment: Sending a POST request to an external domain, won't work if that endpoint does not have CORS enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the client side you can NOT make a request into any other domains (not even the same domains different port like :81) then the host itself. This is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

However there are some workarounds to just proxy such requests, see [Q: Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery?lq=1) and [Q: Ajax cross domain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call?rq=1)