# Connect to PHP MySQL with Javascript from external server

Tags: php, javascript, html

Okay here is the problem. I have the following PHP code.

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Which I got off of [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and works fine when on the server that the database is on. However what I want to do is display that on another site using the following Javascript.

```
    function displaydata()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("datalist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","phpscripthere.com/myphp.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The above javascript works but only when it is on the server that the database is on. What I need is to get the Javascript to work on another location while the PHP can still be stored on the main server.

Comment: Javascript has a cross domain policy that blocks requests going to other domains. You'll need to enable CORS or use JSONP to get this working.

Comment: FYI
http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: Alternatively you can call a page on your server by ajax which fetches the remote page by using CURL.

Comment: It should be mentoined here, that you lose security when using jsonp, ie. there is no post, so all data posted will be exposed to the user, all routers in between and the web servers, each of them logging the information.

Answer (score 4):

Please do not mark this as answer, since it is not.

But this is rather recommendations.

This is w3Schools virus spreading....

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

In this script **processing continues** even when the **connection fails**.

You should incorporate more failure checking and exit on them like this:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   exit(0);
}
```

Also you do not know if

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
```

query is successfull.

Apart from these pitfalls

You should better collect your data for the page and encode it into JSON and send to the client.. as Follows:

```
$r = array();
while(true){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(!$row)break;
    $r[] = json_encode((object)$row);
}
echo json_encode($r);

forming [  {"firstName":"John", "lastName": "Smith"}, 
           {"firstName":"Abraham", "lastName":"Lincoln"}, ...etc ]

then upon receiving decode the data in js and inject to your page.
```

And of course use ajax cross domain requests (less secure) or make your server talk to the others (more secure) to solve your problem.

Comment: It's great to teach people the right stuff, but should this be an answer or a comment?

Comment: Wait the rest is coming. I am not after reps, I start to encounter the same thing agin and again.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I understand W3Schools is just their to teach and not necessarily their to give the best practices.

Comment: @Ihsan Wait a second. I'm a tad bit lost. So let me see if I can post an example of what I'm getting from you to see if I understand you or not.$r = array();
while(true){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(!$row)break;
    $r[] = json_encode(object($row));
}
echo json_encode($r);

forming [  {"firstName": $row['FirstName'], "lastName": $row['LastName']}]

Comment: What I was posting was the same thing as you but I replaced John with a variable and Smith with a variable. I also would most likely add a loop to it since the DB will always be changing.

Comment: Uh ! Oh I got it wrong, It should be (object)$row, sooo sorry... Corrected now...

Answer (score 3):

You need make cross domain request [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+cross+domain](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20cross%20domain) (some of them [AJAX cross domain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call) )

Comment: Thank you I went to the site you refered me to. I downloaded the files from GITHub I will look threw them.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make a request using $.ajax with cross domain true like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
crossDomain:true,
url: "phpscripthere.com/myphp.php"
});
```

Comment: I understand the AJAX code you posted. It looks alot like Javascript. However I have a some other questions should AJAX be in the <head></head> or should it be refrenced <script src="location"> also what extension do I give AJAX if it is in a seperate file. .JS?

Comment: you can call above ajax method in <head></head> or some other part in the <script>  *code here * </script> part .If you want to call it from another file then that should be a JavaScript file with extension .js and need to be included in the <head> of page.

Comment: Just make sure you have jQuery JS included.

Answer (score 1):

If you're learning this stuff off of W3Schools, it may sound just a little little bit complicated, but don't be discouraged :)

Anyway, like @LoneWOLFs said in a comment, you could probably also set up another PHP page on the same server where your JavaScript comes from, and make that page call on the other remote server.

Basically, your new PHP script would do the similar as the old one - call some data from some remote location. And then it would pass that data back to the browser that called it.