# using jQuery to get cross domain csv file

Tags: ajax, jquery, csv, cross-domain

I'm trying to load some .csv file from remote servers (so I have to deal with domain problem), and I'm using jsonp with the following code

```
sql="a csv file link"

$.ajax({
url:sql,
dataType:'jsonp',
}).done(function(){
    console.log("done");
}).error(function(){
console.log("err");
}).fail(function(){
console.log("fail");
}).success(function(){
console.log("success");
});
```

Some how, this piece of code gives me 2 different result.

1) On certain csv file links, it seems to be getting the complete csv file. However, there is an error saying that the csv file has a "syntax error", and .error and .fail is executed.

2) On some other csv file links (something like.http:// host.com:port/file.csv? select from table), somehow nothing happens. The .done/.success are not called, nor the .fail/.error are called

Can anyone tell me the solution or possible causes of those above problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remore server allows [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), use something like the following:

```
sql="a csv file link"+"?callback=myFunc";
```

Where myFunc is a user defined function to process the data from the remote server.

Another technique is to use a proxy as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2559062/1186628

[Update]

here is a very simple example of what myFunc might look like:

```
function myFunc(data){
     alert(data);
}
```

Comment: umm, could you give an example of the myFunc?? Really appreciated :)