# Ajax Call cross domain

Tags: ajax, apache

Hi I am making an Ajax call cross domains but on the same machine.  In apache I have created a virtual host and setup ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.

when I make my ajax call in ie It works but on all subsequent calls it returns the same value, even though I know this value has changed.

In chrome I get the error Origin

```
         http://myip is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Do I still have some configuration in apache to do or do I need to change something in the browser??

thanks for any thoughts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique called [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Basically you need to spacify a special HTTP haeder to allow cross domain access:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

If you have installed the mod_headers you can try to add this line to your htaccess file or server configuration:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com"
```

If you want to allow general access from all domains like for public API allow all domains with the asterisk:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```