# ajax call not working when trying to send data to localhost:8000 from localhost

Tags: php, ajax, django

When I'm trying to make an AJAX call from `php (localhost)` to `django (localhost:8000)`, it throws the following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8000/project/login/uid=bimt;token=KAMWMS151UWP67Q.
>   Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```
$(document).on('click', '.login', function(event) {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var token = $('#token').val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost:8000/project/login/uid=" + username + ";token=" + token,
       success: function (html) {
         alert(html);
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the port is not the same, it's considered a cross origin request.
You must set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the script you are requesting.

Learn more:

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

or, specifically for django:

http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/27/using-access-control-allow-origin-to-make-cross-domain-post-requests-from-javsacript.html

Answer (score 1):

1) php does not make ajax requests.  php executes on the server side; javascript executes on the client side, and it is js that makes ajax requests to the server.

2) js does not allow you to make ajax requests to a different host than the one from which the current page was obtained from.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX, by default, can't make cross-domain requests.

You should refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call).

Answer (score 0):

Try, something like:

```
$('#yourClickButtonId').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'project/login?uid='+$('#usename')+'&token='+$('#token'),
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

You should just use a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I swapped my internal IP (192.168.1.x) in the place of localhost and was able to call a XMLHttpRequest on it. This should do the trick without messing with cross origin policy.