# Ajax not sending request to localhost on same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have a node (express) server running at `localhost:3000`. On another hand, I have an HTML (`client.html`) file which is served by the server itself, on the route `/client` (the file is sent as the response).

My goal here is to access another route, namely `/test` using an AJAX call on the `client.html` page (WHICH IS SERVED BY THE SAME SERVER). However, as it's quite obvious from the post, it isn't working.

**Not a duplicate**: I have tried the solutions given in the following SO posts, so far, without success:

• [jQuery Ajax request from local filesystem (Windows file:///) - though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469440/jquery-ajax-request-from-local-filesystem-windows-file) 

• [ajax call not working when trying to send data to localhost:8000 from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285895/ajax-call-not-working-when-trying-to-send-data-to-localhost8000-from-localhost)

• [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Here are my source codes.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
...
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.send('This server does not support GET requests.')
})

app.post('/test', (req, res)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.send("response from /test")
})

var port = 3000
var server = app.listen(port)
```

**client.html**

```
<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/test',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }).done((data)=>{
                alert(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="javascript:init()">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried sending both a `GET` and a `POST` request but none of them worked.

I have done this before, only not with `nodejs`. When I send a request from a **Python** script, using the `requests` library, the response is received, so the server *seems to* work just fine.

**FYI**, I'm on Windows.

Where and/or what is the issue in?

Comment: Please check with `console.log(req.body)` in your `/test` route

Comment: why are you sending CORS headers at all? no need for that

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah but I'm at that point rn that I'd try almost anything ...\

Comment: have you tried using `res.end()` to signify the end of the response?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. `res.end()` produced the same results.

Comment: what do you observe in your browsers development tools console / network tab regarding the request?

Comment: @NathanFries I just checked with `console.log(..)`. Nothing is shown when the HTML page is supposed to have made an AJAX call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197418/discussion-between-progyammer-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: So the client is not making the call. Try using `/test` as the complete `url` in the ajax call

Comment: Three points: 1. Since `GET` requests are not supported how you are getting client.html from `localhosat:3000`? 2. Secondly, can you just try POST to `/test` endpoint instead of the complete URL? 3. Unless these resources are not from  same host and port you'll face issues but I see you are allowing CORS.

Comment: @fiveelements GET requests **are** supported, as I have defined the get handler for that route. I am just sending out a message to whoever accesses the root (since there's nothing to do on the root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with your client code (after I added missing jquery import) following which seems to work well (I havent use express):

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("logging stuff")
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.write('This server does not support GET requests.')
    res.end();
});
```

I would suggest to run curl on your terminal to see what headers you actually get back - `curl -I localhost:3000`.

Comment: missing jquery was the issue. I need some sleep. Thanks, Pavel :-)