# Multiple domain names for one website and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp, multiple-domains

My website has two domain names that points to the same folder on my server.

I've implemented a module that uses AJAX and it works perfectly when I acces my website through www.domain1.com but fails when I access it through www.domain2.com.

I've looked around and I see a lot of post about [cross domain AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) and [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) but I was wondering if there would be another option in my case.

Since it has technically the same origin, is there a way around this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Comment: Without using jsonp, CORS, or a server-side proxy, no. cross-origin is still cross-origin regardless of server setup.

Comment: In my case, I fixed it by using a relative url in the script. Thx for your comments though.

Answer (score 2):

What is the sense to have 2 domains names and absolutely the same content?

Anyway, you need just to use the same domain as initial page is loaded, so you will have no cross domain calls

Comment: In other words, use a domain relative url. `url: "/somefolder/somefile.php"`

Comment: Thx for the answer.

I have 2 domain names pointing to the same content because I manage 2 languages on the same website and there is a domain name per language. Does that make sense ?

Comment: By curiosity, I've tried with a script that uses absolute urls and changes the url: "url" depending on the domain the request was sent from and it didn't work. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie open browser's developer tools and check what requests are actually made