# xmlhttpRequest to pass URL in xmlhttp.open()

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cgi-bin

I am in a scenario where I have to pass a URL in `xmlhttp.open` to another server.I know that `xmlhttp.open` can be used to pass a URL on the same server. I want this URL to be passed on to another server and get the response back to the calling server.I had tried the following way(Scenario2):

**Scenario1:**
Conventional way that works fine for same server:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../cgi-bin/perlcode.pl?root="+str+"&lang="+lang+"&out_notation="+out_notation,true);
```

**Scenario2:**
Request to be sent to another server:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://abcxyz.com/cgi-bin/perlcode.pl?root="+str+"&lang="+lang+"&out_notation="+out_notation,true);
```

In the first case I can get the response back on to the same server.In the second case I can't get the response back, but I can see that the request is passed onto the server abcxyz.con and it is processing the required result.

**Question:** Had I chosen a correct way.If so how to get back the response or else what are the other alternatives that I can choose with.

**Note:** I had chosen `xmlhttp.open` method so that I can get the result on the same web page without clicking submit button.

Comment: Learn about the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and you will see why it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use XMLHttpRequest to request to another server (origin), according to the Same origin policy.

However, you can use some workarounds like:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP