# Disable Dates in UI Date Picker from Array

Tags: sql-server, arrays, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I have asked similar questions before but I am stuck on something and wondered if you could help, I am writing a function to disable dates in my UI-Datepicker and these dates are in an array. The dates are being populated from a SQL Server table , then placed in an array and now I want these dates to be disabled. I am still relatively new to programming, I hope this question hasn't been asked before.

My current code:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var count === 0;
var BankHolidays;

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM CompanyBankHolidays", connection);
rs.MoveFirst;
while(!rs.eof) {
    count = count + 1;
    BankHolidays[count] = (rs.fields(1));
    rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;

function IsBankHoliday(date) {
    ///HELP HERE PLEASE//
}

$(function () {
    $(".startdate").datepicker({
    minDate: ('+1d'),
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [(!IsChristmas(date) && !IsNewYearsDay(date) && !IsWeekend(date))];
        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $(".enddate").datepicker({
    minDate: ('+1d'),
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [(!IsChristmas(date) && !IsNewYearsDay(date) && !IsWeekend(date))];
        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".startdate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: For this approach I would like to suggest that never fire SQL queries from the javascript. Because any one can tamper with then and hack the database.

What you should do is create a server side file(.asp,.php or whichever is your choice) and call that file from AJAX

Comment: I have a global.asa file, can I use that? @Shiva

Comment: I hope that should work, what output you get after its execution, if possible please post it.