# How to print content that is returned in http response using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, response

I want to print in console content that are returned in http response. For example when I go to https://google.com and in the tab Network I can see content such as scripts, text, document, png. I want to print names of all .png files.
I tried to use something like that:

```
function hand () {
        console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type'));
}
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', 'https://google.com', true);
x.onreadystatechange = hand;

x.send();
```

But it doesn't work for me. This action below is assigned for the button on me page.

Comment: Your problem is [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Are you make a ajax call in the same domain or different?

Comment: @Mike OP specified google.com

Comment: @Mike It is not ajax call

Comment: @Mike It was just action on the button. Sorry, I'm new for this. Should I use ajax?

Comment: ok. I am looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-origin requests simply [are not allowed by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The remote server may provide permission to your application through [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or by supporting Ajax alternatives like [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

**Edited:**

The only (easy) way to get cross-domain data using AJAX is to use a server side language as the proxy as [Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call/2559062#2559012) noted. Here's a small sample how to implement that using jQuery:

The jQuery part:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        address: 'http://www.google.com'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // response now contains full HTML of google.com
    }
});
```

Simple as that. Just be aware of what you can or cannot do with the scraped data and be very much aware that such a proxy is a severe security hole. At least make a list of acceptable addresses and don't just blindly accept any passed address. Have a look at a decent proxy script here: [PHP Simple Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)