# AJAX: loading content cross-domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain

I'm trying to load html content cross-domain using ajax. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            crossOrigin: true,
            url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSONP",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divTest").html(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {

            }

        });
```

`#divTest` is a `<div>`, but ajax always returns empty data with no error message. I tried setting crossOrigin, crossDomain properties as suggested, but without success. Can someone look and let me know what I'm missing ?

Also: is there any better and secure way to load html content cross-domain?

Update: After implementing the latest jQuery, it gets status code 200 and thinks of it as success.

Comment: Cross domain request has to be enabled in the server, which your `url` refers..

Comment: might be thjis helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Comment: You only can make cross domain requests to a site that **allow/support such requests**

Answer (score 0):

I got a little workaround with Cross-Domain-Stuff:

Request a PHP File and let it download the Content for you:

```
./dl.php?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
```

Because Webpages give out there Content, but don't like it Framed or by Ajax.

The PHP Script is as simple as:

```
<?=file_get_contents($_GET["URL"]); ?>
```

Of course you may add to this, but it'll work too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with getJSON method of jquery Ajax, here are some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)

But your [server](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) should also allow cross domain