# Javascript, ajax, cross domain call, overriding Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I parse a web-page and depending on content, I need a ajax call to my localhost.
On local host will be a PHP script that will exchange data via AJAX, probably in JSON format (I'm not sure yet, still reading and testing).

This is a plugin and I try to test over Google page

https://www.google.de

I follow this simple ajax example:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp

I successfully made the call itself

```
//loadDoc("http://localhost/index.php", myCallback);  <-- this NOT
//loadDoc("https://www.google.de", myCallback);   <-- this WORKS

/*
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
*/

function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
 };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}


function myCallback(xhttp) {

  alert("I'm alive from my local server");

}
```

The (BIG) problem is that I discovered the "Content Security Policy" will not allow me to make calls to other domains, even if I'm in my own context (my browser, FF 53).

Now seems that this can be easily tricked at least for GET requests like I need, by inserting a script in the DOM, like this

[AJAX cross domain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call)

and especially this great post of Rob W

[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

So I tried like this, but still not working.

```
// var actualCode = ['/* Code here. Example: */' + 'alert(0);',
                  // '// Beware! This array have to be joined',
                  // '// using a newline. Otherwise, missing semicolons',
                  // '// or single-line comments (//) will mess up your',
                  // '// code ----->'].join('\n');

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://localhost/index.php";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.appendChild(script);
// script.textContent = actualCode;
// (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
// script.remove();
```

The security is not a concern since I'll use my localhost only.
What I miss here?

EDITED

Those are errors shown by Firefox debugger

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://localhost/index.php”[Learn More]  axtest.js:16
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
```

Comment: If your CSP doesn't allow you to access remote scripts, but you want to access remote scripts … why not just change your CSP?

Comment: @Shilly — It's CSP not CORS.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, hence I added the PHP knowhow is limited. I got confused by the cross domain ajax call link. So use the correct CSP header instead of add the correct CORS header.

Comment: @Quentin how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append it to the body or head element, not the root `document`:

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The mixed active content error is due to loading the initial page over https(SSL) and then trying to load a http (unsecured) URL. Either load the page without https or setup https on the URL you're calling.

Comment: The same, google working, localhost not :( see edited for errors

Comment: thanks, accepted because of mixed protocols, now working

Answer (score 0):

Despite I already accepted a answer, I found a much easily solution that works in my case. **It's all about local browser security policy, no need to inject any JS code**.

First, plugin's manifest.json had to be updated with this

```
    "permissions": [
      "history",
      "browsingData",
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>",
        "http://localhost/*",
        "storage"
  ]
```

Second (thanks @Quentin) local browser policy needs to be re-configured. Turn off the CSP for your entire browser by disabling security.csp.enable in the about:config menu

Comment: Not sure telling users to turn off significant browser security features is a "solution"