# Ho to send ajax request for file in same directory

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to create app when I an put url to input field and get some information about request(title of page and response code). I read many topics and understood that I can't send request to another domain like "google.com" and others. Then I created file in directory with my html file named hi.php and send request like this:

```
<script>
           function getInformation() {

                 $.ajax({
                     type:"POST",
                     url:"http://localhost/test/hi.php",
                     success:function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                     }
                 });
             }
    </script>
```

but still have error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

how can I fix it? What I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with a relative path? i.e. _/test/hi.php_ or _/hi.php_

Comment: Did you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call

Comment: Please try searching error messages before asking

Comment: plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain