# ajax not working in firebase production environment but works on local host

Tags: ajax, firebase-hosting

ajax not working in firebase production environment but works on localhost ajax code

`var settings = {
            "async": true,
              "crossDomain": true,
              "url": "https://some_other_domain:3000/",
              "method": "POST",
              "dataType": "json",
              "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
              },
            "processData": false,
            "crossDomain":true,
            "timeout": 3000,
            "data": JSON.stringify(emailData)
        }
        $.ajax(settings)
        .done(function (response) {`

on firebase-hosting my request timeout(as seen on network tab in inspector, and console doesn't show any errors). on localhost it works fine. I tried on Mozila Firefox and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call foreign domain using AJAX due to AJAX [cross-domain policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call) is an alternative way to get data from a foreign domain.