# 404 Bad Request in ajax call in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel, there is a get request to following url:

> http://localhost/Script/login/fb

but i am getting :
404 Bad Request in my console, and the control goes in the fail block. Please help to sort out my issue.

> layout.blade.php

```
body.on('loggedIn:fb', function(){
    if(!User.isLoggedIn()) {
            $.get(BASE_PATH + '/login/fb').success(function(response){
                User.setData(response.user);
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

                body.trigger('social-login:error', jqXHR.responseText);
            }).always(function(){
                loginModal.removeClass("logging-in");
            });
        }
    });
```

> routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/login/fb', array('as' => 'loginWithFb', 'uses' => 'UserController@loginWithFb'));
```

Comment: Check your url... console.log(BASE_PATH + '/login/fb');

Comment: @AlekseiMaide: Url in console is http://localhost/Script/login/fb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3653474/user3653474 maybe port number missing then? localhost:8000/login/fb or whatever port number you have.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide: Tried changing the port but the same issue. Port on which my wamp server is running is 80

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the port".. the url doesn't contain any port number...

Comment: This issue is only in the ajax request, normal request is working properly. I mean the port on which wamp server is running.

Comment: localhost:80/Script/login/fb hardcode this instead of BASE_PATH + '/login/fb' and try then...

Comment: @AlekseiMaide : Tried the static url but the same error message.

Comment: oh well :D, must be something with CORS then... maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call helps... good luck.