# Can javascript download a target URL into a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the same question, and it was not answered at all.
We are asking for a function that can be passed a URL and
returns a list of anchor tags. I do it in VB all the time.
We keep getting answers on how to get anchors from the page
we are on. If you are suggesting we go to the page to get the
document.whatever...
How can we run our scripts we left back on the page we left?

Comment: You can certainly grab the entire DOM of a website with a simple AJAX request... but I've got no idea what you mean about returning a list of anchor tags. Are you asking how to return a collection of every `ID` on the target page?

Comment: like this: var myPage = function(some_URL) { someCode.. return(text) }

Comment: results: <a href="url">text</a><a href="url">text</a><a href="url">text</a>

Comment: _“I have the same question, and it was not answered at all.”_ - if you are referring to an existing question, then you should give a link to it. Without context, there is no “same”.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in arbitrary html to jQuery functions - so if using jQuery is acceptable, then try something like this;

```
$.ajax("https://example.com").done(function (data) {
    let list_of_anchors = $(data).find("a");
});
```

This will fetch `https://example.com` and then use jQuery to parse and find the `a` tags for you. You can then do what you like with them.

If you are doing this, you may run into issues with cross-site scripting. Questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call) one have information on that topic.

Comment: thank you. that helped.   i learned that as a security feature, javascript cannot get pages outside of it's domain. my question was about the language, not how to accomplish the task.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to tick the answer if it has helped you :)